# My device doesn't show the Allow USB Debugging dialog

Tags: android, android-studio

My Android Studio shows 'Allow USB debugging from your device', but my device does not show that dialog:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfOMm.png]

I have tried the following, but nothing worked:

1. Adb kill-server
2. Adb start-server
3. Kill adb process from Task Manager
4. Restarted both the computer and the device
5. Selected both MTP and PTP connections in my device's USB debugging settings.

Comment: Which device do you use?

Comment: samsung j5 i used but it happens in any device

Answer (score 15):

In my case I have to set the "Select USB Configuration" which is under "Networking" in the "Developer Options" from Charging to MTP(Media Transfer Protocol) for the dialog to show

Comment: This worked for my OnePlus 8 Pro, Android 12.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. Had to set mine to "USB Tethering" (instead of "Transferring files / Android Auto")

Comment: Mine too; I had to set to PTP; I was trying every option hahah

Comment: I didn't see that option, but tapped an option that said "Default USB configuration", then hit back, and I heard the sound on Windows of a device disconnecting and then connecting, and then the debugging prompt showed up on my phone.  All without my changing any setting.

Answer (score 14):

A different, hardware-oriented approach:

Are you sure the cable you're using does allow for data transfer?
Some cheaper cables - usually sold with chargers - don't allow for anything else than charging.
**Try another cable**, and see if that works.

Comment: Worked for me.  What a pain.  I would have never thought of this.  I just tried to replace my cable, and the new one doesn't even work!

Answer (score 5):

This is what solved my problem, appears that the public key might have been missing from my computer, causing the issue. Removing the private key solved the issue.

- browse to the C:/Users//.android directory and delete
  adbkey and adbkey.pub
- do adb kill-server
- do adb devices
- watch for an "Allow USB debugging" prompt in the headset

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/OculusQuest/comments/bu4946/im_on_pc_and_there_is_no_allow_usb_debugging/)

Comment: use this one, and working two times with different devices. thanks

Answer (score 5):

I just solved this problem on my Samsung by going into developer options>debugging and selecting "Revoke USB debugging authorizations. After this I reconnected my phone to my PC and the dialog finally appeared.

Comment: This worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

Try this step:

1. **Tools** > Connection Assistant (it will appear in the right side of the android studio once you click it)
2. Click the Rescan USB devices
3. Click the next buttons
4. It should appear the device connected to your computer or try to restart ADB Server if device does not appears in the panel.

sample screenshot below

[image]

Hope it helps to fix your problem

Answer (score 2):

I might have had a different problem to everyone else, but in my case, I had some stale public/private keys for USB debugging. The fix was to:

- Go to `C:\Users\myUserName\.android` (if you're using Windows)
- Delete `adbkey` and `adbkey.pub` files

After I plugged in the Link cable, the familiar Windows USB chime sounded (which wasn't working at all before) — and I got the "*Allow USB Debugging*" notification on the headset.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is interested, here is how I authorized my PC without the Dialog showing for unkown reseaons (requires device to be rooted):

1. Go to C:\Users<profile_name>.android\adbkey.pub
2. Copy the file to any location in your phone using USB cable.
3. Using Root Explorer, move the adbkey.pub onto this location: /data/misc/adb/
4. rename it from adbkey.pub to adb_keys and allow read and write permissions
5. Reboot the device.

Now, your devices will be authorized as if you clicked the Authorize button on the Dialog.

Answer (score 1):

for me it was vice versa. "from Charging to MTP(Media Transfer Protocol) for the dialog to show" but from MTP to charging (i prefer charging in general)

Comment: Based on the comments from others just changing this can be helpful, and it helped me as well. Thanks!

Comment: thx for the upvote. it's nice to see that there are also good people on this site. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the driver on your system with respect to attached device

In window system

- Go to **manage** by right click on **My computer**
- **System tool** then **Device manager**
- Check your device here
- Right click on device and **Update Driver software**

Answer (score 0):

On my Zebra device (Android 7.1.2) I had to change "Select USB Configuration" which is under "Networking" in the "Developer Options" from MTP (Media Transfer Protocol) to Charging for the dialog to show.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this.
Resolved using factor reset, none of the other solutions worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Off and on, USB debugging option in Developer options on device

Answer (score 0):

Try turning your USB-C cable around.

I met this problem using a Sony Xperia XZ2 Compact with a slightly noname USB-A to USB-C cable. None of the other options helped, but as soon as I turned around my cable it worked each time. Still have to find out which is the erroneous one (phone connector or cable).

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything else listed here (as of this post datetime), and the trick I used to finally get it to show up on a Samsung Note 9 was to:

- In Android Studio (Hedgehog) open the **Virtual Device Manager** under *More Actions* on the home screen (Projects).
- That's it! The auth prompt finally popped up on the phone.

[image: Screenshot of 'Virtual Device Manager' option under 'More Actions' on Android Studio home screen]

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this issue with my phone Android 11 after I rooted it. I resolved the issue by disabling and then re-enabling Developer options

Disable Developer options in the Developer options menu.